# How to select ALL nodes on canvas(sigma.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, sigma.js

I'm looking for way to select all nodes by a hotkey(maybe <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, doesn't matter) on canvas by using sigma.js on my project. 
Plugins like a lasso don't solve my issue.

```
hotkeys.prototype.selectAll = function(event) {
        var tag = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (event.keyCode == 65 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea' && this.ctrl && !this.shift) { // Ctrl + A
        {
            document.nodeSelector.select();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize it by myself. Thanks for your answers =(

```
hotkeys.prototype._selectAll = function(data) {
    var i,node;
    var nodes = s.graph.nodes();
    var selected = [];
     for (i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
        node = nodes[i];
        selected.push(node);
    }
    document.nodeSelector.select(selected);
}

hotkeys.prototype.selectAll = function(data) {
    var tag = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (event.keyCode == 65 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea' && this.ctrl && !this.shift) { // Ctrl + A
        this._selectAll();
    }
}
```